# How to loop through an array once the previous are has looped?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, setinterval

I'm making a decorative text, that prints out one letter until it forms a word, then deletes that word character by character to write a new word. I have all the strings being turned into an array, and i know i probably need to use .length, .slice(), and .join. but the one thing that has me stumped is how do i start the next array once the previous one has looped?

```js
const skillData = {
  js: [..."javascript"],
  ts: [..."typescript"],
  reactJS: [..."reactJS"],
  html: [..."HTML5"],
  css: [..."CSS3"],
  reactNative: [..."React Native"],
  node: [..."NodeJS"],
  mongo: [..."MongoDB"],
  phaser: [..."Phaser 3"],
  py: [..."Python"],
};

let arrayClimber = 0;
const moveSkill = () => {
  if (arrayClimber < skillData.js.length) {
    arrayClimber += 1;
    console.log("going up " + arrayClimber);
  }

  //Needs to start going down then one it reaches zero it should change to the typescript, reactJS, etc arrays
  console.log(skillData.js.slice(0, arrayClimber).join(""));

};

setInterval(moveSkill, 150);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Change the skillData object to an array
- Keep record of the current word with a currentIndex variable
- Create a 'finished' boolean to stop the execution of the setInterval when the array is done being iterated on.

```js
const skillData = [
  [..."javascript"],
  [..."typescript"],
  [..."reactJS"],
  [..."HTML5"],
  [..."CSS3"],
  [..."React Native"],
  [..."NodeJS"],
  [..."MongoDB"],
  [..."Phaser 3"],
  [..."Python"],
];

let arrayClimber = 0;
let currentIndex = 0;
let finished = false;
const moveSkill = () => {
  if (arrayClimber < skillData[currentIndex].length) {
    arrayClimber += 1;
    console.log("going up " + arrayClimber);
  } else {
    currentIndex++;
    arrayClimber = 0;
  }
  
  if (skillData.length == currentIndex) {
    finished = true;
    return;
  }

  //Needs to start going down then one it reaches zero it should change to the typescript, reactJS, etc arrays
  console.log(skillData[currentIndex].slice(0, arrayClimber).join(""));

};

setInterval(() => {
  if (!finished)
    moveSkill();
}, 150);
```

Comment: Thank you this was the simplest/best solution. Although it did not solved the going backwards once it reaches the end of the word, but i worded my question pretty poorly, and i was able to solve it thanks your answer regardless. so thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked out. I hadn't noticed the going back part. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

- Loop over keys of object using `Object.keys` or `for...in`
- Fetch current skill.
- Loop over current skill and print values. You can use `.reduce` or a normal `for` loop

  - Create a variable that will hold the string to be printed. Since it needs to hold value of previous iterations, it needs to be defined outside this loop.
  - Every iteration, you add current character to it and print value.
  - At the end of this loop, you can truncate it or before the loop, you can initialize it to default empty.

**Note:** To prevent console from flooding, I have use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

Also, SO has a limit to values displayed in integrated console. For proper result, check actual browser's console

```js
const skillData = {
  js: [..."javascript"],
  ts: [..."typescript"],
  reactJS: [..."reactJS"],
  html: [..."HTML5"],
  css: [..."CSS3"],
  reactNative: [..."React Native"],
  node: [..."NodeJS"],
  mongo: [..."MongoDB"],
  phaser: [..."Phaser 3"],
  py: [..."Python"],
};

const moveSkill = () => {
  for (const key in skillData) {
    const skill = skillData[key];
    
    skill.reduce((str, char) => {
      str += char;
      console.log(str);
      return str;
    }, '')
  }

};

setTimeout(moveSkill, 150);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know a condition whenever a single word has been printed (and removed in your case). Because of the different lengths of the word I suggest that you use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). With promises you can check a condition of the word has been fully printed and then fulfill the promise.

This gives you the ability to dynamically wait for each word to be printed before starting the next one. With the combination of the iterator protocol you can loop over each promise and wait for it to complete before starting the next word.

The example below uses a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to create such an iterable object which yields a promise for every word that needs to be printed. When looping this object you print every word, wait for it to finish, and continue to the next word in the list.

An advantage of this approach is that you can easily control the timing of each word and the code is non-blocking. So other scripts will run without having to wait for this one to end.

```js
const wordElement = document.getElementById('word');

const skillData = {
  js: [..."javascript"],
  ts: [..."typescript"],
  reactJS: [..."reactJS"],
  html: [..."HTML5"],
  css: [..."CSS3"],
  reactNative: [..."React Native"],
  node: [..."NodeJS"],
  mongo: [..."MongoDB"],
  phaser: [..."Phaser 3"],
  py: [..."Python"],
};

const printWord = (word, speed) => new Promise(resolve => {
  let index = 1;
  let wordLength = word.length;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (index <= wordLength) {
      let partOfWord = word.slice(0, index).join('');
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        wordElement.textContent = partOfWord;
      });
      index++
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      resolve(word);
    }
  }, speed);
});

async function* wordPrinter(data) {
  for (const word of Object.values(data)) {
    yield printWord(word, 100);
  }
}

async function printWords() {
  for await (const word of wordPrinter(skillData)) {
    console.log('Word printed:', word.join(''));
  }
  return 'Done printing';
}

printWords().then(console.log);
```

```html
<p id="word"></p>
```